# I want to control Multiple macbooks, mulitple cursors with 1 input mouse

Tags: macos, mouse, cursor, click

Read this correctly: 
I want to have 5 macbooks sitting next to each other. Each running their own OSX. Each with their own cursor.

Total number of cursors = 5

But i input only 1 mouse. When i move the mouse on the "Master"-Macbook the 4 "slaves" move their cursors to the corresponding place on their screens.

When i click with the master, the 4 slaves click too.

Is their an OSX application that can do this exact scenario for me?

(the use case for this is a bit odd, but basically i run an applescript on each, and each need their own browser window, their own script, their own mac address and their own ip address. And they have to execute at the same time to within 50 milliseconds. I cannot make a  fixed script for the cursor movements since this will change from time to time and not be known before the execution.)

Comment: Would it be possible to make the applescript include a delay to only run the applescript at the next minute marker? Provided all the times are synched, you could wait for a minute to roll over, run all 5 scripts, and they would all execute on the next minute.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The scenario is: i need to run it on 12.00.00 every monday. i need to recognize a picture from a list of pictures on a website, and then click it with the master. at the moment i click, the applescript launches.
Then i want my 4 computers to do that at the same moment, click the same picture. approx 12.00.02. i have only to seconds from i know the cursor position, till my 4 slaves must click and execute their applescripts at the same x,y coordinate. i know the scenario sounds ridiculous. i might get a developer to make a python script for me that can do this.

Comment: Ultimately i would like to run a large number of slave devices, maybe 30-50. but 5 units should explain the case.

Comment: I see. You would be best off having this run via a cron job or some other scripting method rather than using a master/slave mouse setup, but I am curious if anyone can answer your original question as well.

Comment: Ah! i understand your assumption. The thing is, cron job wouldnt do it since my case varies 1-10seconds. sometimes at 12.00.00 sometimes 12.00.09. Basically what i am doing is sitting and waiting at a site for it to load. it loads 50 pictures at approx 12.00.00. I have to click a specific picture, the site then loads the info-site for that picture. On that specific url i need to run the script. But the info-site url isnt predictable before 12.00.00. So i have to click onto the site w pictures, click correct picture, get the info site url. Then run the script within 1-2 seconds of it loading